# Login and Logout Function throwing a Bad Method Call Exception in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting a **BadMethodCallException** in laravel 5.6 when i login and logout users, I don't know where this behavior came from, I'm using the auth scaffolding that ships with laravel.

## Login

> > Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::setCache does not exist.

## Logout

> > Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::pullCache does not exist.

I've tried to run all cache commands `$` `php artisan clear:cache`

I'm using the basic routing and controller that comes with the command

```php
Auth::routes();
```

Comment: it seems like you're using database cache driver, have you migrated the cache table

Comment: `php artisan cache:table` ? I did and migrated it, but m not clear on how it works or how to link it

Comment: try composer dump-autoload

Comment: try **php artisan optimize**

Comment: @RajdipChauhan Command "optimize" is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens due to the cache issue in Laravel. In any case, running following commands should fix your issue:

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: _I still have a problem with the Auth pullCache and setCache_ would you advice me to upgrade laravel from 5.6 to 5.7?